# Puppeteer not returning in time despite being in an await function?

Tags: pdf-generation, puppeteer

I have a Puppeteer function generating a PDF:

```
const generatePdfBase64 = async (html) => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.setContent(html)
    const pdf = await page.pdf();
    await browser.close();
    console.log("PDF Generated")

    const pdfBase64 = new Buffer.from(pdf).toString('base64');

    return pdfBase64
}

const generatedPDF = await generatePdfBase64(html)

doSomethingWithPDF(generatedPDF)
```

This is generating the correct string, but doSomethingWithPDF is proceeding before the pdfBase64 is returned in the generatePdfBase64 function. How could this be? And how to fix?

Comment: Are you sure your original script is the same as the example you've posted? For me this script works perfectly, `doSomethingWithPDF(generatedPDF)` is executed after `generatePdfBase64(html)` is finished. Maybe there is an async problem in the way how you pass the `html` param to the function (e.g. you are downloading it from a remote source with another function and that one is not awaited correctly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was missing an await in some code upstream-- the above should work!